# TOMCAT 7 not deploying war

Tags: tomcat7, war

I have developed a Dynamic Java Project with Eclipse which involves web services(RESTful). After completion I tried to run my project Tomcat 7 runtime of Eclipse IDE, it works fine. I am able to access all my web services. 
But, when I created a WAR file out of my project by right-clicking on project and exporting it to WAR file and placed .war file in Tomcat 7's webapps folder. Started the tomcat by running startup.bat, it throws below exceptions and I am not able t access any web service:
I have placed all the required jar files in lib folder of Tomcat.

1. Exception fixing docBase for context [/Books] (Books is my war file name)
2. Failed to create work directory [{CATALINA_HOME}\work\Catalina\localhost\Books]
3. Failed to create destination directory to copy resources.

Could anyone please let me know what I am missing??

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Piyush

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace of the exception please ?

Answer (score 0):

The failed to create "work directory" error can occur if the work folder does not exist in the tomcat7 folder.

Also this error can be caused by tomcat not having sufficient permissions to read, write and execute in the tomcat7 directory.

Comment: Give a solution for fixing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because, tomcat is not finding your web.xml location in the classpath.

Do below steps:

**Right click on web project-->Properties-->Deployment Assembly--> Add your classpath to web.xml**(src/main/webapp) in my case.